# Translating XML with CDATA using OpenAI GPT-4 and maintaining CDATA structure

Tags: python, xml, openai-api, cdata, gpt-4

I'm using OpenAI GPT-4 to translate XML content from English to French, and I'm facing an issue with preserving the CDATA structure in the translated XML. The XML contains strings with CDATA sections, and I want the translated output to maintain the CDATA structure.

Here's a simplified example of the input XML:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">RoomThermometer</string>
    <string name="instructions" formatted="false">
        <![CDATA[
        <b>How it works? </b><br />
        The thermometer app is using your phone temperature sensors to measure room temperature.<br /><br />
        <b>Why this thermometer is the best one?</b><br />
        We use AI-powered algorithm to get the most accurate measure by ± 3°C. The more you use the thermometer, the more accurate it is!<br /><br />
        <b>How to get the best room temperature measure?</b><br />
        You want to prevent the phone from overheating, follow the next steps:<br />
        <b>1-</b> take your case off<br />
        <b>2-</b> Your phone is charging or just charged, let it cool down<br />
        <b>3-</b> Turn off unnecessary apps running in the background<br />
        ]]>
    </string>
</resources>
```

The current Python script uses OpenAI GPT-4 to translate the text, but the CDATA structure is not maintained in the output. The result looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Thermomètre de Chambre</string>
    <string name="instructions" formatted="false">
        '&lt;b&gt;Comment ça marche?&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
        L'application de thermomètre utilise les capteurs de température de votre téléphone pour mesurer la température ambiante.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;b&gt;Pourquoi ce thermomètre est le meilleur?&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
        Nous utilisons un algorithme alimenté par l'IA pour obtenir la mesure la plus précise à ± 3°C. Plus vous utilisez le thermomètre, plus il est précis!&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;b&gt;Comment obtenir la meilleure mesure de température ambiante?&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
        Vous voulez éviter que le téléphone ne surchauffe, suivez les étapes suivantes:&lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;b&gt;1-&lt;/b&gt; retirez votre coque&lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;b&gt;2-&lt;/b&gt; Votre téléphone est en charge ou vient d'être chargé, laissez-le refroidir&lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;b&gt;3-&lt;/b&gt; Arrêtez l'application inutile qui fonctionne en arrière-plan&lt;br/&gt;'
    </string>
</resources>
```

However, I want the translated output to preserve the CDATA structure, like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Thermomètre de Chambre</string>
    <string name="instructions" formatted="false">
        <![CDATA[
        <b>Comment ça fonctionne ? </b><br />
        L'application thermomètre utilise les capteurs de température de votre téléphone pour mesurer la température de la pièce.<br /><br />
        <b>Pourquoi ce thermomètre est le meilleur ?</b><br />
        Nous utilisons un algorithme alimenté par l'IA pour obtenir la mesure la plus précise à ± 3°C. Plus vous utilisez le thermomètre, plus il est précis !<br /><br />
        <b>Comment obtenir la meilleure mesure de la température de la pièce ?</b><br />
        Vous voulez empêcher le téléphone de surchauffer, suivez les étapes suivantes :<br />
        <b>1-</b> retirez votre étui<br />
        <b>2-</b> Votre téléphone est en train de charger ou vient de se charger, laissez-le refroidir<br />
        <b>3-</b> Fermez les applications inutiles qui tournent en arrière-plan<br />
        ]]>
    </string>
</resources>
```

I think that the problem is in this function:

```
def translate_xml_file(xml_file_path, target_language="French"):
    # Parse the XML file
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()

    # Iterate over each 'string' element
    for string_element in root.iter('string'):
        # Check if the element contains text
        if string_element.text:
            string_text = string_element.text.strip()

            # Check if the text is within a CDATA section
            if string_text.startswith("<![CDATA[") and string_text.endswith("]]>"):
                # Extract the content from CDATA
                cdata_content = string_text[9:-3]

                # Translate the content
                translated_cdata_content = translate_string(cdata_content, target_language)

                # Manually wrap with CDATA and set back to element
                string_element.text = "<![CDATA[" + translated_cdata_content + "]]>"
            else:
                # Translate normal text
                translated_text = translate_string(string_text, target_language)
                string_element.text = translated_text

    return tree
```

If you need the whole code, I will share it! I am not sharing it, because it is too long!

How can I modify the existing script to achieve this? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Information:

I'm using OpenAI GPT-4 for translation.
The script is written in Python.
The target language is French.
I want the translated text to be wrapped in CDATA just like the original structure.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please heed the *minimum* in [mre]. We don't need all your code only the small relevant parts that reproduce the problem such as how you pass input XML into the translation process. And at very least please show us what packages you use especially the XML parser: etree or lxml or other?

Comment: The fact that you use Open AI for translation seems irrelevant here. I presume that you use ElementTree, which does not preserve CDATA sections. There are ways around that (for example by using lxml). See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[elementtree]+cdata.